# Automatic Assessment Configuration In iOS

Tags: ios

We want to use Automatic Assessment Configuration to lock the device with Automatic Assessment Configuration,

Queries:

- How to enroll in Assessment Developer Program
- Can there be both iphones & iPads which can be used for assessment applications
- Will this assessment developer entitlement/program allow 200 devices or we need iOS Developer University Program for AAC mode
  The iOS Developer University Program allows instructors and professors to create a development team with up to 200 students.

Can anybody help me in these things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Session 716 from WWDC17 explains how to apply for the AAC entitlement for your app. Once you have a provisioning profile with that entitlement then the standard limitations for your particular developer program membership will apply

Answer (score 0):

As Paul's said, I found my answers from [WWDC 2017 - Session 716 - iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/716/)

For Enable App Lock request

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(true) { didSucceed in
        self.log("Enable App Lock request - \(didSucceed ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")")
    }
```

For Disable

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(false) { didSucceed in
        self.log("Disable App Lock request - \(didSucceed ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of iOS 13.4 and macOS Catalina 10.15.4 you have access to the following framework https://developer.apple.com/documentation/automaticassessmentconfiguration. For both iOS and macOS you need a special entitlement, so you have to ask Apple to grant you access to that one. You have to use it wisely, following the rules - strictly for assessment apps.