# Is it possible to detect the use of floating/multi-windowed apps while my app is running?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, mobile

Our project is a mobile based examination app. The app should be able to detect the use of floating apps/multiwindow and app switching while taking an exam. We're supposed to use xamarin for this project.

If the student used a floating/multiwindow app or switched to another app, the exam activity should terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about **iOS**. It is possible. System has a bunch of execution states:
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) I will talk about one of them.

Inside of the `AppDelegate` you can get the exact moment that users are leaving the app.

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move from the active to inactive state...

```
// Swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  // ...
  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: You can also set your app to "requires full screen" to prevent side by side apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765157/is-it-possible-to-opt-your-ipad-app-out-of-multitasking-on-ios-9

Comment: There is also automatic assessment configuration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909134/automatic-assessment-configuration-in-ios